# Doubt about the Grothendieck universes

Tags: set-theory

If $U$ is a grothendieck universe, by definition:

- $I \in U$ and $\forall i\in I$ $x_i \in U$ $\Rightarrow \bigcup_{i \in I}x_i \in U$.

Is $\forall i,j \in I$: $i \neq j \Rightarrow x_i \neq x_j$ and underlying assumption of these property?

N/A: I'm reading Basic Category Theory Vol 1 of Francis Borceux.

Edit: If the answer is yes, I interpret this property as *if $I \in U$ then every union of $|I|$-elements of $U$ belongs to it.* By the other side, if the answer is no, I think about it as *if $I \in U$ then every union of $\mathbb{at}$ $\mathbb{most}$ $|I|$-elements of $U$ belongs to it.* That is the origin of my question.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no particular reason to assume that, the notion of union makes sense even if there are some redundancies.

Of course, you can reduce to that situation because you can remove the redundancies, but there's no need to; it would make for a more complicated statement, both to assume, and to work with.

Comment: I interpreted this property as *if $I \in U$, then every union of $|I|$-elements of $U$ belongs to it*; but considering your answer I must change that to *if $I \in U$, then every union of $\mathbf{at most}$ $|I|$-elements of $U$ belongs to it*